# Can't Upload File To Github Organization Repository

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have an organization on GitHub, and I am trying to upload the file on my local to the [repository](https://github.com/mutiaradakwahcom/referensi-copy) at the organizations on GitHub.
First, I created a repository with the same name as on my local. Second, I ran the `git remote add origin https://github.com/mutiaradakwahcom/referensi-copy.git` on git bash. Third, I run the code `git push -u origin main` on git bash, but the following error message appears:
error: `failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mutiaradakwahcom/reference-copy.git'`.

Comment: What branch names do you have in your local repository? How many commits are there?

Comment: Did you clone that repo or did you do a `git init` locally?

Comment: can you post your output of  git status?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
It seems this is because I haven't changed the branch name on my git, so the branch names between my git and GitHub are different